# Hiding Dropdown Fields

Tags: custom-field

I'd like to hide a field based on the selection of separate field.
Basically, I'd like to only display the "State" dropdown if United States is selected from the "Country" dropdown.

I have downloaded and installed Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields but I'm having difficulty with the coding and setting the conditional fields.

[image]

Or do I have to download the Modules plug-in and hide the fields in the email?  Our forms are getting hung up transferring to Salesforce because the "State" field isn't selected if the "Country" field is selected.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you asked in the CF7 forums?

Comment: No I have not yet.  I will do that now.  Thank you for the suggestion!